# fitting Tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a pulse under each beam to indicate its intensity but the sizes are not working with me

```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, quotes} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
                    
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{myplot/.style={ samples=50, smooth, no marks,hide axis}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style={rounded corners},
      declare function={
        normalpdf(\x,\mu,\sigma)=
        (2*pi*\sigma^2)^(-0.5)*exp(-(\x-\mu)^2/(2*\sigma^2));
      }]
    \foreach \x in {2,...,10}   
        \shade[draw,shading=radial, inner color=red!\x0,draw=white]
                ({10-\x},0) circle (1/\x);
               
      \begin{axis}[  myplot]
    
    
        \addplot[smooth, thick, domain=1.2:2.2]
        {normalpdf(x,1.7,.3)} {};
        
    
      \end{axis}
     
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Minimal" Working Example implies that there is no unnecessary code. `tikzstyle` is out-of-date now, use `tikzset` instead, etc. What do you mean "the sizes" ?